# Using Rowstyle with S-column of siunitx

Tags: tables, formatting, siunitx

Is it possible to use a rowstyle with S-column provided by sinuitx? When I try the following the S-column does not allign the numbers (they are not even recognized as actual numbers):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{+}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{+l^c^r^S}
\rowstyle{\bfseries}
    A & B & C & {Number}\\
    a & a & a & 3.14 \\
    b & b & b & 12.1 \\
    c & c & c & .333 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I also tried using other symbols for the columntype commands - without success. Without the rowstyle the S-column works without a problem.

Maybe there is a solution using dcolumn but there are problems reported when using icomma and I would like to have the formatting of siunitx all over my document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{+}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\empty}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{+l^c^r^S}
\rowstyle{\bfseries}
    A & B & C & {Number}\\
    a & a & a & 3.14 \\
    b & b & b & 12.1 \\
    c & c & c & .333 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just figured out that the solution works well for the example above. Unfortunately latex runs on endlessly when the first column behind + is an S column. Until now I could not figure out why.